# How to create a new post on Google+ via javascript API?

Tags: google-plus

I move with the Google+ API for a while now but I have noticed that some sites that create posts in our profile with Google api in a different way.

A regular posting, a box would pop up Google+ to share, but this site https://bufferapp.com/ can share a post show cash Google+.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot programatically share a post to a Google+ user's stream with any of the public APIs. Any attempts to post without the user initiating the post are [not allowed by the developer policies](https://developers.google.com/+/policies#posts_to_stream_and_notifications).

BufferApp appears to use the Google+ Pages API, which is access that is only granted to a few companies. This API does not allow for posting on behalf of individuals.

If you had a [Google Apps domain](http://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/business/), you could use the [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/), but that creates posts only within the domain, which are not public or visible to people outside of your domain.

Comment: but this site here https://bufferapp.com/ can do this, create post without the box to share Google+

Comment: BufferApp appears to use the Pages API, which is restricted access to only reputable, established companies. Apps that try to circumvent the APIs violate the policies and are regularly blocked.

Comment: So if i was a very big company, like say BBC for example, they might allow me to post via java script to the users wall if they had initiated it?