# Google Domain API keeps returning 401/403 in responses. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, google-plus, google-domain-api

I'm trying to make a simple activity insert to an authorized user's Google+ profile using the Google Domains API. It seems that this API is only available for Google Apps (now G Suite) accounts and ISVs, and so I created a G Suite account. This after multiple attempts made with a regular Google developer account, for which I was getting the same errors shown here.

Ideally, I'd like to achieve this via HTTP endpoints as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating).

I have created a google app and generated the OAuth2 CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET, and I have enabled the Domains API of course.
The following Java code shows the steps taken to achieve my goal.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GooglePlustShenanigans {

    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "<client_secret>";

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "<client_id>";

    private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "https://www.someuri.com/oauth2callback";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                CLIENT_ID,
                CLIENT_SECRET,
                SCOPE)
                .setAccessType("offline")// Set to offline so that the token can be refreshed.
                .build();
        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();

        System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then " +
                "type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = flow.newTokenRequest(code)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();

        String token = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
        String refreshToken = tokenResponse.getRefreshToken();

        System.out.println("Access token: " + token);
        System.out.println("Refresh token: " + refreshToken);

        post("Sample message", token);
    }

    public static void post(String msg, String token) throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities");
        StringEntity body = new StringEntity("{\"object\":{\"originalContent\":\"" + msg + "\"}," +
                "\"access\":{\"items\":[{\"type\":\"domain\"}],\"domainRestricted\":true}}");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth" + token);
        post.setEntity(body);

        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        System.out.println(resp.toString());
    }
}
```

Here's the response I keep getting:

```
401
Unauthorized
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Vary: Origin, Vary: X-Origin, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2017 00:38:07 GMT, Expires: Sat, 11 Feb 2017 00:38:07 GMT, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: GSE, Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34", Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity@1649b0e6}
```

My next attempt was to try and leverage Google Java libraries and ended up with the following:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
                .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                .build();

        credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
        credential.refreshToken();    
String msg = "Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays";

    // Create a list of ACL entries
    PlusDomainsAclentryResource resource = new PlusDomainsAclentryResource();
    resource.setType("domain"); // Share to domain

    List<PlusDomainsAclentryResource> aclEntries =
            new ArrayList<>();
    aclEntries.add(resource);

    Acl acl = new Acl();
    acl.setItems(aclEntries);
    acl.setDomainRestricted(true);  // Required, this does the domain restriction

    PlusDomains plusDomains = new PlusDomains
            .Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
            .setApplicationName("myApp")
            .build();

    Activity activity = new Activity()
            .setObject(new Activity.PlusDomainsObject().setOriginalContent(msg))
            .setAccess(acl);
    activity = plusDomains.activities().insert("me", activity).execute();

    System.out.println(activity.toPrettyString());
```

Output:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

I got the same 403 error when I tried achieving this via the API Explorer.

And then for no specific reason I tried:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: OAuth$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN" -d "{"object": {"originalContent": "Happy Monday!#caseofthemondays"},"access":{"kind":"plus#acl","items":[{"type":"domain"}],"domainRestricted":true}}" -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE: I tried creating posts for an authenticated G Suite domain user, and got the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

To work with google plus domain api you need create account http://apps.google.com/ and then use this user to create post. But!!! They create posts domain restricted. I've not finde way how to create public post for now.

Please refer this links for more...

[Google Plus Creating a Post - Rest API -Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503640/google-plus-creating-a-post-rest-api-forbidden)

[How to create a new post on Google+ via javascript API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075306/how-to-create-a-new-post-on-google-via-javascript-api)

[How to post in Google+ wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-wall)

hope it helps you...